# Select Query with Backtic is not working on MySql v5.7.31

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

One of my query i.e

```
SELECT `*`,user_id FROM tb_users WHERE 1=1  AND user_id = 1
```

was working on MySQL v5.7.29 with Node.js v10.9.0, and sending me the result as all the data along with user_id. But on v5.7.31 it is not working.

Need Help.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Where are the back-ticks? Enclosing *?

Comment: Asterisk shoudn't be wrapped with backticks.

Comment: MySQL uses back-ticks for delimited identifiers. Do you have a column named `*`?

Comment: *was working on MySQL v5.7.29 with Node.js v10.9.0*  This can be Node.js pre-parsing issue (backticks were removed simply).

Comment: @jarlh yes it is.

Comment: @jarlh no we dont have any columns named as * but on running the above query in v 5.7.29 as `*` it send me all the data

Comment: Actually the function is made in such a way to append the columns we need to get in the select query.